# Round slider textbox always visable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slider, round-slider

I am using http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html round slider library. I want to show the editable textbox always show not hide. Thank you

Comment: then i would recommend learning that first. :) all the best

Comment: I found this [site](http://jquery.com/) to be very usefull

Comment: @CerlinBoss i found roundsliderui.com/demos.html this. They show textbox on mousehover but i want always visible inside textbox in this

Comment: Please edit your post and include the code that you have tried so far. You may want to create a demo at jsfiddle.net. Until then, no one will be able to help much more than @CerlinBoss has done.

Comment: @nawaz I also read through the Demos you suggested and none of them show `<textbox>` nor is one rendered. You'll need to clarify the issue further.

Comment: @Twisty Thanks. This one http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/LpuLe9tr/343/. Please you mouseover in circle inside value (45) they will be show a textbox .I want this textbox  always visible

Comment: Ok, I see, where you can enter a value. This is created upon the Click event and not Mouseover event. The documentation does not have a feature that would enable the ToolTip to be a input upon creation. Might be able to use one of the other functions like `beforeCreate` or float a  input over the slider.

Comment: If possible you can write for me some code@Twisty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Understand, you should supply the code and can get help or suggestions from people here. I took the example you provided and made some changes.

Here is a Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/Lorej7up/

**HTML**

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
  <div id="slider">
  </div>
  <input type="text" id="myToolTip" class="rs-input rs-tooltip-text" style="height: 27px; width: 32px;" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slider-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.slider-wrapper input.rs-input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 95px;
  left: 93px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
function updateToolTip() {
  $("#myToolTip").val($("#slider").roundSlider("option", "value"));
}
$(function() {
  $("#slider").roundSlider({
    sliderType: "min-range",
    radius: 110,
    width: 10,
    startAngle: 90,
    value: "82",
    showTooltip: false,
    editableTooltip: false,
    drag: updateToolTip,
    change: updateToolTip
  });
  $("#myToolTip").val($("#slider").roundSlider("option", "value"));
  $("#myToolTip").change(function() {
    $("#slider").roundSlider("option", "value", $(this).val());
  });
});
```

Comment: I am very grateful and appreciative. long live :)

Comment: Please this is my very genuine issue. If possible please help me @twisty

Comment: @nawaz I do not know what you mean. We addressed your question. If you have a new question or new issue, you will need to post a new question. Members will not write new code for you, but can offer help in fixing the code you're trying to use. Otherwise you should consider hiring Website UI Developer.

Comment: Yeah i made new question but no answer yet made http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710368/half-color-of-roundslider