# Half color of roundslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, round-slider

I am using [Round slider](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html)  library. This is my demo site [Demo link](http://demo.glowsol.com/myskinrecipes.com/wizard/level-of-oil/?product_t=48).My circle have Two color one of Gray and other Orange. if i move handle Black color is showing. but i want just show this black color in gray colot not to upto orange. Means i want  to eliminate black color from orange part. Below image can also explain [image]

Comment: I suspect you just need to adjust the `width` property when you create the RoundSlider. Maybe try `15` instead of `30`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation here: http://roundsliderui.com/document.html#width

> **width**
>   Indicates the width (or thickness) of the slider.

So maybe try this:

```
$("#slider").roundSlider({
  sliderType: "min-range",
  radius: 160,
  startAngle: 90,
  endAngle: 216,
  min: 0,
  max: 35,
  value: 0,
  width: 15,
  handleSize: "20,0",
  handleShape: "square",
  change: "valueChange",
  drag: "valueChange"
});
```

Changing the `width` property from `30` to `15` should change the width of the slider.

Comment: Thank you so much. I know this property. But now i lost orange color. I want these both color. But width up to gray color.  i am using this one image for background which have both color You can see http://demo.glowsol.com/myskinrecipes.com/wizard/images/outer-border.png.

Comment: I want to keep my background image. #slider .rs-range-color color  only on gray color.

Comment: I want to keep my background image just reduce to black color.

Comment: Please provide a working example in jsfiddle.com or the like.